# Call AlertDialog Method with parameters inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

im doing an app for my project but im not sure what to pass in my method.

Heres how i call the method:

```
public void scanBar(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.barcode_scan_btn:
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                showDialog(getActivity(), "No Scanner Found", "Download the scanner application?", "Yes", "No").show();
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

And here is my method:

```
private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                act.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            }
        }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });

    return downloadDialog.show();
}
```

Here is the error:

```
09-20 05:20:31.774  17032-17032/app.psiteportal.com.psiteportal E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.psiteportal.com.psiteportal, PID: 17032
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method scanBar(View) in the activity class app.psiteportal.com.psiteportal.DrawerMainAdapter for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'barcode_scan_btn'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3994)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: scanBar [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3987)
```

I dont know if where should i put my method either in the activity or in the fragment. pls help

EDIT: Do i need to change the parameter to Fragment or just Activity?

Comment: Did you declare the `scanBar()` method as an onclick callback method (using `android:onClick` inside your layout) ?

Comment: hi @cylon, thanks for your reply, it seems i can just use setOnClicklistener inside the fragment coz i have read that it is really an issue, i hope there will be a fix soon or maybe i just dont know how, how dumb of me.  have a nice day!

Comment: I just have explained this within an answer. Feel free to accept it :)

Comment: I would even recommend to delete all `android:onClick` attributes from your xml layouts. You really do do not want such a tight dependency between xml layouts and java. It is much more comfortable to rely on the ID's and use `setOnClickListener()` for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your method `scanBar()` was declared as onClick callback (inside your layout). This won't work in fragments.

"The Activity hosting the layout must then implement the corresponding method." - [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B)

Its not a bug. If you would like to implement callback in this way, you must use activities instead of fragments.

So the solutions is to set an onClick listener, like this:

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {/* Some Code */ });
```